# Android getListView() change function to Gridview

Tags: android, listview, gridview

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Hashmap for ListView
    albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading Albums JSON in Background Thread
    new LoadAlbums().execute();


    // get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {
                   .................
        }
    });
}
```

Hello, this is my code how I get ListView and create setOnItemClickListener. However, I need to create GridView instead of ListView.

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

How can I change this line to get a GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand from your code is that you are loading images from internet into a gridview . You should follow these steps to properly load gridview with images -

1 -Add a gridview in your layour and get it like

```
GridView gridView = mView.findViewById(R.id.yourgridId);
```

2 - Then define a class that extends BaseAdapter that will hold data for your GridView and populate your GridView with it and override it's getView() method which will be your Layout of a Single Grid.

3- call `gridView.setAdapter(adapter);` to set up adapter with your gridview

4- Load images in background thread and add a listener for response

5 - As you get response in listener , add images to your Arraylist<Bitmap> in Adapter class and call notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh your GridView

Answer (score 4):

> Though you accepted the answer to use GrdView, but still i would like to
>   raise my voice that RecyclerView is more better and optimized than ListView
>   and GridView.
>
> **Still i would like to recommend using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead of
>   ListView or Gridview.**

**Following are some point to encourage usage of RecyclerView**

Android created RecyclerView as a ListView improvement, so yes, you can create an attached list with ListView control, but using RecyclerView is easier as it:

1. **Reuses cells while scrolling up/down** - this is possible with implementing View Holder in the listView adapter, but it was an optional thing, while in the RecycleView it's the default way of writing adapter.
2. **Decouples list from its container** - so you can put list items easily at run time in the different containers (linearLayout, **gridLayout**) with setting LayoutManager.

   Example:

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
**or**
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));

3. **Animates common list actions** - Animations are decoupled and delegated to ItemAnimator.
   There is more about RecyclerView, but I think these points are the main ones.

So, to conclude, RecyclerView is a more flexible control for handling "list data" that follows patterns of delegation of concerns and leaves for itself only one task - recycling items.

Answer (score 0):

Define the `GridView` in your layout.

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```